# NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Dear fellow rails programmers,

I am facing a little problem on my collection_select form_tag
the project i am working on contains 3 seperate major models: 
customers, 
owners,
addresses.

One customer can have multiple owners and addresses while each address can assign an owner

the problem i am facing is that i cant seem to assign owner to address

in my address controller new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@address) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :id, @customer.id %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :unit %>
  <%= f.text_field :unit, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :tel %>
  <%= f.text_field :tel, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :working_hours %>
  <%= f.time_select :start_at, {minute_step: 30} %> to 
  <%= f.time_select :end_at, {minute_step: 30} %>

  <%= f.label :owner_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :owner_id, @owners, :id, :name, {include_blank: 'Please Select'},%>
.
.
.
<%= f.submit "Add new address", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

in address.rb

```
def new
  @address = Address.new
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @owners = Owner.find_by(customer_id: params[:id])
end
```

I am facing an error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
>   Did you mean?  tap):

with the code above.. but when i replace

```
@owners = Owner.find_by(customer_id: params[:id])
```

with

```
@owners = Owner.all
```

this page will load and the select dropbox will allow me to select ALL OWNERS in my Owners table.. i would just like to search for Owners with customer_id = params[:id]..

P.S - both address and owner table has customer_id column and address.rb has_many :owners, and owner.rb belongs_to :address

Can anybody help me? thanks and much appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Owner.find_by` returns at most **one** record. Whereas you need a collection. Use this instead:

```
@owners = Owner.where(customer_id: @customer.id)
```

Comment: thanks! this helped. right now i cant seem to pass the data when the collection_select dropbox is set to include_blank: "please select" any where i left out?

Answer (score 2):

`find_by` returns a single record or nil. Neither of these objects support `map`. This is why you see the error message.

You should use `where`:

```
@owners = Owner.where(customer_id: @customer.id)
```